# what is the reason why we can not open a project created in VS2008 using VS2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Why Microsoft does not support Forward comparability?

Comment: Your notion of backward compatibility is.. backward. Backward compatibility means that 2008 can open a project created using 2005.  If it meant what you're asking for, we'd never be able to add certain kinds of new features to software.

Comment: @Sandeep, out of curiosity, how would *you* implement this?  (sincerity intended)

Comment: You are not referring to backward compatibility, you are referring to forward compatibility. This would be a neat trick if Microsoft could pull it off.

Comment: @John Maclntyre I wish I know the answer :)

Comment: @Joel: Usually backward compatibility means two things: (a) The new version can read files created by the old version (Visual Studio does this), and (b) The new version can write files in the format readable by the old version, although it may default to a newer format the user has the option of the older format (Visual Studio does not support this).  A one-way conversion does not generally earn the term "backward-compatible".

Comment: @John: With a "Save as VS2005 solution" option in VS2008, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is actually [forward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility).

The reason is that VS 2008 may (hypothetically) include settings in the solution file which change the rules of the game for how the solution should be processed, using mechanics that were not invented at the time of VS 2005. Assuming that these settings can break the solution if not processed correctly, what should VS 2005 do when it encounters them?

Comment: As Sandeep mentioned is his comment it should be an option in VS 2008 to save solution in VS 2005 format. Just like in MS Office 2007 - you have an option to save document in old doc format.

Comment: @DixonD: In MS Office there is a warning that says something like "Hey, you might lose some formatting and fancy colors if you do that. Are you sure?". What should it say in VS? "Hey, your project may not be viable in VS 2005 format, would you like to test your luck?" for example? Computer programs are not like documents, where "almost correct" may be good enough.

Comment: This is not computer program, it is just format of solution file. Cannot see problems with my analogy to MS Office. "The solution cannot be saved in older format" in case when it is impossible to save. What's wrong with this?

Comment: @DixonD: Minus 100 points is what is wrong with it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

That's not backwards compatibility it's forward compatibility. You can open a VS2005 project with VS2008 (backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried simply changing the version number at the top of the file? (it's one of the first 3-4 lines IIRC)